# Интеграция аналитических сервисов в десктопные продукты на MacOSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios, xcode, google-analytics

Всем привет.

Хочу поделится с Вами своим опытом интеграции аналитики в десктопное приложение.
Месяц назад мы зарелизили наше приложение под MacOS, но что-то в нем не так. Для того чтобы разобраться, что именно не устраивает наших пользователей мы решили внедрить аналитику и провести анализ. Начали смотреть какие есть аналитические сервисы и как они работают. Стоит признаться что с iOS в этом плане намного проще, тот же Flurry и GA заточены исключительно под мобильные платформы.

Первый сервис который мы нашли был [DeskMetrics](http://deskmetrics.com), но дальше создания аккаунта мы не продвинулись. У них нет триала и возможности хотя бы в демо режиме просмотреть как он работает. Все доступно только после оплаты.

Вторым сервисом был [TrackerBird](http://www.trackerbird.com). Скачали их SDK, добавили себе в проект статическую библиотеку (плюс ко всему кучу фреймворков на которые она депендится). Вот как выглядит в коде сама инициализация аналитики:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
 {
 NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString* url = @"http://58614.tbnet1.com";
 NSString* productID = @"2383168965";
 NSString* productVersion = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
 NSString* productBuild = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (id) kCFBundleVersionKey];
 NSString* currentLanguage = [[mainBundle preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex: 0];
 TBConfig* config = [[TBConfig alloc] initWithURL: url productID: productID productVersion: productVersion productBuildNumber: productBuild multiSessionEnabled: NO productEdition: @"" productLanguage: currentLanguage filePath: nil];
 [TBApp start: config completionBlock: nil];
 [config release];
}
```

Уже здесь у нас возникли вопросы. Зачем разработчику самому передавать аналитике такую информацию как версия продукта, номер билда и текущая локаль, почему аналитика сама не может внутри себя получить эту информацию и упростить процесс интеграции. Ну да ладно с этим можно мирится. Системную информацию аналитика выгребает сама, но что она берет тоже не совсем понятно.

В результате теста билда нашего продукта с аналитикой TrackerBird обнаружился блокер, на сноу леопарде (MacOSX 10.6) в оффлайн режиме любое обращение к апи SDK, инициализация на старте запуска, стоп на закрытии или просто отсылка сообщения инициирует креш приложения. С таким дефектом мы релизится не смогли.

Следующей на очереди была [TapStream](https://tapstream.com) аналитика. Исходники этой аналитики открыты в публичном доступе на gitHub-е. Аналитика просто интегрировалась в наш продукт и показала правильные результаты при тестировании. Единственным дефектом было отсутствие оффлайн режима, все сообщения шлются в синхронном режиме. В нашем случае это тоже было критично, так как мы хотели получить всю информацию.

Прочитав статью о новом аналитическом сервесе [ZeoInsight](http://zeoinsight.com), мы сразу приступили к его изучению. Для интеграции SDK в наш продукт мы добавили их фреймворк к себе в проект и написали код для инициализации аналитики:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
 [ZBAnalytics setProductKey: @"e64a3e83-764a-4bb8-b843-e055b7c8706d"];
 [ZBAnalytics setEnabled: YES];
}
```

При такой интеграции SDK, мы получили шесть базовых сообщений, пять базовых метрик, и смогли видеть отчеты по всем хардварным характеристикам и гео-данным.
По умолчанию SDK работает в асинхронном режиме, все данные архивируются и кешируюся в кешах приложения, что обеспечивает корректную работу без потерь в оффлайне. И кстати это единственное SDK с которым у  нас получилось собирать честную статистику нашего приложения которое состоит из нескольких процессов. В нашем приложении запускается основной процесс и хелпер, так вот все вышеперечисленные SDK трекали отдельно запуск и инсталл каждого процесса.
Разобравшись с самой аналитикой мы решили остановится на ней. Далее нам нужно было насетапить порядка 50 сообщений для отслеживания поведения пользователя, и здесь самое интересное. В ZeoInsight SDK есть возможность обрабатывать все действия пользователя без необходимости добавления кода в обработчик действия или же изменения элементов интерфейса. То есть чтобы получить в статистике ивент нажатия на кнопку мы вместо того чтобы в екшене этой кнопки слать свое сообщение, записали его в “Event Manager”, в админке.

Интеграция SDK и настройка всех сообщений заняла у нас порядка одного часа. Сейчас уже выпустили второй релиз с аналитикой ZeoInsight, без каких либо изменений, связанных с аналитикой.
На основании данных полученных от ZeoInsigh мы выявили, что наши пользователи не совсем понимают как пользоваться нашим продуктом. В результате мы подтюнили интерфейс и поменяли текста. Сейчас смотрим, что покажет новый билд.

Какие аналитические сервисы Вы используете в своих продуктах? С какими аналитиками приходилось работать и какие там есть подводные камни?

Answer (score 0):

Я учавствовал в бета-тестировании http://devmate.com — понравилось. Интеграция в проект довольная простая, плюс приятный (хоть и довольно перегруженный на мой взгляд) веб-интерфейс.
Вообще это инструмент специально для OS X приложений, да и сами MacPaw им пользуются, например.

Answer (score 0):

Мы использовали google analytics, сейчас переходим на [dev2dev](https://www.devtodev.com) - они недавно расширили поддержку платформ и теперь доступны не только на айфонах.